# HTC Zoe: Any way to turn it off?

Tags: htc-one

So, in my bank app, I am used to being able to photograph the front and back of a check to be deposited. This worked fine with my Moto Razr Maxx. With my recently acquired HTC One, now running Kit Kat (but even on Android 4.3 before), it doesn't work -- the app doesn't accept the photos the One takes. I'm wondering if this is Zoe. A three-second vid is not a snap of a check. Can Zoe be turned off for simple point-and-shooting?

Answer (score 1):

Zoe is not used in any app aside from the HTC camera app. The mobile banking app will have just basic access to the camera where it can take pictures and in some apps, toggle the flash. If it is not accepting your pictures, it may not be taking clear enough photos or the lighting may be insufficient. Or it could be the app itself. You may wish to try better lighting and be sure to hold absolutely still when taking the pictures. If not, contact the developer of the app for assistance.

As for turning Zoe off, it is toggled on and off in the camera app with the button on the opposite side of the screen from the shutter/video button.